# Regular expression brackets containing any letters

Tags: regex

I need to find brackets that contain any letter.
for example:

```
a17(1d34) xc
```

the previous brackets contain the letter `d`.
So I need to find:  `(1d34)`

Comment: So you need to match string within parentheses when it contains a specific character? What lang or tool? What have you tried?

Comment: If your engine supports a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you might try [`\((?=.*?[a-z].*?\))[^)]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/hMzfmz/1)

Comment: Can you post more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex can do the job:

- `\([^a-z]*[a-z]+[^a-z]*\)` with flags `g` and `i`

You can test it with the [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/p7IPNw/3) at regex101 to check if it works with all the cases you expect.

Also I don't know the language you are using, regex101 let's you generate code for some.

**Breakthrough**

- `\(` matches the literal opening bracket
- `[^a-z]*` matches any character before the letter that is not a letter (can be nothing)

  - the `^` character right after an opening range inverts the match
- `[a-z]+` matches at least one letter
- `[^a-z]*` matches any character after the letter that is not a letter (can be nothing)
- `\)` matches the literal closing bracket
- the flag `i` (case insensitive) extends the range `a` to `z`, to uppercase also
- the flag `g` (global match) lets you match multiple times

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works like charm in .net.

Answer (score -1):

`/\((?:\d*[A-Z]+\d*)+\)/gi` will match your brackets that contains at least 1 letter.

```
var rgx = /\((?:\d*[A-Z]+\d*)+\)/gi;
rgx.exec("a17(1d34) xc"); //(1d34)
```